# all but one of my objects are not visible in the 3d viewport

Tags: objects, 3d-view

as you can see in the screenshot linked below, all but one of my objects are not visible nor interactable in the viewport. They are not hidden, nor disabled in the viewport.

It also is not the clipping distance or anything to do with collections, since they're all in the same one. I have been using blender for a year now and never encountered this exact problem before.

I don't know when it happened since I had them hidden while working in edit mode, and then when I switched back to the object mode and unhid them, they still didn't appear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your .blend file? https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: @SlickRed added it now.

Answer (score 1):

You have the local view of objects activated, the local view is used to isolate one or more objects from the view to work easier when you have several objects, to deactivate it press the / key on the numpad, or go to the menu View > Local View > Toggle Local View

[image]